# Where is the default Powershell log file location in Windows?

Tags: powershell, logging

Where is the default Powershell log file location in Windows? So surprise that I can't google this up easily.

Comment: There are multiple, depending on the type of telemetry you're looking for.

Comment: The issue was probably that you googled for log and not history. The list of commands previously entered into a shell is called history.

Answer (score 0):

Found it

%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\PSReadline\ConsoleHost_history.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Windows Event Viewer (click windows button > type "event viewer")to view the powershell logs (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging?view=powershell-5.1

[Image of answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb06y.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).